decompressed bitmap image fails to render properly for no obvious reason when using winGDI
I have been trying to make my own custom PDF editor & I have made a PDF parser that works absolutely fine for any PDF feature until images came up. First of all, the images in my PDFs are compressed with the standard DEFLATE/INFLATE algorithm & they all have the FlateDecode filter. the images, compressed & decompressed will have a lot of raw bytes that may be corrupted as a string or a char so I used a vector of uint8_t to be safe. here's my decompression/inflation function :
std::vector<uint8_t> parser::inflate_stream_to_raw(const std::vector<uint8_t>& deflated_stream) {
    z_stream stream{};
    int ret = inflateInit(&stream);
    if (ret != Z_OK) std::cout << "\ncould not init zlib\n";

    std::vector<uint8_t> inflated_stream;
    const int chunk_size = 16384; // 16 KB chunk size
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(chunk_size);

    stream.next_in = const_cast<Bytef*>(deflated_stream.data());
    stream.avail_in = static_cast<uInt>(deflated_stream.size());

    while (ret != Z_STREAM_END) {
        stream.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(buffer.data());
        stream.avail_out = chunk_size;

        ret = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        if (ret == Z_STREAM_ERROR || ret == Z_NEED_DICT || ret == Z_DATA_ERROR || ret == Z_MEM_ERROR) {
            std::cerr << "Error: zlib stream error. Error code: " << ret << std::endl;
            inflateEnd(&stream);
            return {}; // Return an empty vector on error
        }

        inflated_stream.insert(inflated_stream.end(), buffer.data(), buffer.data() + chunk_size - stream.avail_out);
    }

    inflateEnd(&stream);

    return inflated_stream;
}


this supposedly works fine, a version of this that returns the data as a string has worked fine for the PDF contents without any issues. So, when it comes time to render it, I have a .bmp that is the same as the image in the PDF i am testing & its size is about 12 MB, & testing the size of my decompressed image stream it is also around 12 MB, so I don't see how it could be the decompression failing. But when I get it to render, it looks like this:  
I've tried many ways to even get the bitmap image to render & this is the only way that seems to work so I don't know how to fix it if it is a problem with winGDI or how I render it. here;s the code I use to render it:
#include <C:/code-libs/pdfCoder/pdfCoder.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#pragma comment(lib, "C:/code-libs/pdfCoder/pdfCoder.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK main_wnd_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);
HWND main_wnd;

std::vector<image_object> img_objs;
parser pdf;

int pt_to_dip(double pt, double dpi) {
    if (dpi == 96) return static_cast<int>(std::round((pt / 72) * dpi)); // if DPI is 96, then PX & DIP are equal
    else return static_cast<int>(std::round(((pt / 72) * dpi) / (dpi / 96))); // else find PX first then convert to DIP
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE cur_instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, LPWSTR cmd_line, int cmd_count) {
    const wchar_t* MAIN_WND = L"main_window";
    WNDCLASS wc{};
    wc.hInstance = cur_instance;
    wc.lpszClassName = MAIN_WND;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = main_wnd_proc;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    pdf.open("C:\\Coding Projects\\test field\\test4.pdf");
    objects_root pdf_root = pdf.get_root();
    page_object page = pdf.parse_page(pdf_root.pages[0]);

    img_objs = pdf.parse_page_images(page);

    main_wnd = CreateWindow(MAIN_WND, L"File Organiser",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        1500, 1500,
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    if (main_wnd == NULL) return 1;

    ShowWindow(main_wnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(main_wnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK main_wnd_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param) {
    HDC hdc;
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        OutputDebugStringA("\nPAINTING...");
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        for (const image_object& img_obj : img_objs) {
            OutputDebugStringA("looping images");

            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << img_obj.image_stream.size();
            OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());

            BITMAPINFOHEADER bmp_header = {};
            bmp_header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmp_header.biWidth = pt_to_dip(img_obj.width, 96);
            bmp_header.biHeight = -pt_to_dip(img_obj.height, 96);
            bmp_header.biPlanes = 1;
            bmp_header.biBitCount = img_obj.bits_per_component * 3;
            bmp_header.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmp_header.biSizeImage = 0;
            BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
            bmi.bmiHeader = bmp_header;

            void* raw_bits = malloc(img_obj.image_stream.size());
            if (raw_bits != nullptr) {
                memcpy(raw_bits, img_obj.image_stream.data(), img_obj.image_stream.size());
            }

            StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, 1500, 1500,
                0, 0, pt_to_dip(img_obj.width, 96), pt_to_dip(img_obj.height, 96),
                raw_bits, &bmi,
                BI_RGB, 
                SRCCOPY);

            free(raw_bits);
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, w_param, l_param);
    }
    return 0;
}


any help as to what on earth is happening is appreciated, I couldn't find much on here about showing raw bitmap data instead of from a .bmp file.
To clarify, that image is mesnt to be a fox sitting in snow with a blurred background
This is the picture K J sent me in PDF as raw 24 bit (3x8bit) bitmap with narrow band of colour at top 1/3 (842 pixels as 2562 bytes) red (#FF0000) 1/3 green (#00FF00) 1/3 blue  (#0000FF) thus 7,686 bytes perline in 2562 colour triplets.

Output from above code attempt

EDIT: Some other reasearch has told me that the BI_RGB flag expects data to be in BGR not RGB? is this true? the RGB data extracted from the PDF is still in the /DeviceRGB colour space, do I need to convert to another colour space like sRBG to have the image rendered correctly? can someone clarify?
EDIT2: thanks for clarifying, it seems that BI_RGB & DeviceRGB & the term RGB in general of course mean that the Red Green & Blue values are used to represent colours but not the order in which they are used, it can either be RGB or BGR, as for sRGB, that is a calibrated type of RGB but is not relevant. Once I switched the Byte order from RGB to BGR for the fox image, the fox's colour has mostly corrected itself, but that leaves me with a question: How am I supposed to check what the byte order is if all I have is the image stream, both compressed & decompressed as well as the PDF image object ( 4 0 obj<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 4431385/Subtype/Image/Width 2562/Height 1602/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Intent/RelativeColorimetric/Interpolate false>> ) to work with? For example the test image K J sent me with the coloured boxes is still in an RGB format, if my code is set to BGR then that image is not rendered correctly & vice versa, I need a reliable way to do this & I need it to be efficient since my program should preferrably be under 5MB (it is 0.8MB right now). Additionally I still have the issue of the striping effect that lingers on my image & the repetition of the image (though that may be because of faulty resizing) here is the fox image with the program set to read from BGR byte orders: the fox image when read as BGR, not RGB
As always, all help is appreciated.
EDIT 3: I need to get this done sooner or later, if I render at the image's original size instead of downsizing for the window area, then the striping effect it less noticeable but still there & now there are these white runs, I am not sure exactly what these things are but could it be possible that my image has an alpha channel? black & white parts of any image I test always end up striped this, way, like that coloured box image, Here's the fox image right now: the fox image when not resized, the stripes are black & white now, also, why is the fox repeating itself like that? that;s not meant to happen? for those who need it here's the original image: what it should look like do I need to account for stride & padding & add those factors to the raw_bits stream? here's my code as of now:

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmp_header = {};
            bmp_header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmp_header.biWidth = pt_to_dip(img_obj.width, 96);
            bmp_header.biHeight = -pt_to_dip(img_obj.height, 96);
            bmp_header.biPlanes = 1;
            bmp_header.biBitCount = img_obj.bits_per_component * 3;
            bmp_header.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmp_header.biSizeImage = 0;
            BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
            bmi.bmiHeader = bmp_header;
            int stride = ((bmp_header.biWidth * bmp_header.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4;
    
            void* raw_bits = malloc(img_obj.image_stream.size());
            if (raw_bits != nullptr) {
                memcpy(raw_bits, img_obj.image_stream.data(), img_obj.image_stream.size());
                // this switches a BGR byte order image back to an RGB byte order if needed, so far I have no way to detect which byte order an image is in
                uint8_t* pixel_data = static_cast<uint8_t*>(raw_bits);
                for (size_t i = 0; i < img_obj.image_stream.size(); i += 3) {
                    std::swap(pixel_data[i], pixel_data[i + 2]); // Swap red and blue bytes
                }
            }
            // StretchDIBits will 'resize' the image to fit the window but that isn't really what it seems to be doing
            StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, bmp_header.biWidth, pt_to_dip(img_obj.height, 96),
                0, 0, bmp_header.biWidth, pt_to_dip(img_obj.height, 96),
                raw_bits, &bmi,
                BI_RGB, SRCCOPY);
            free(raw_bits);
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            break;


EDIT 4: sorry for all these mistakes but the image's /Height & /Width is not measures in PDF units as I originally thought, the striping goes away when I use the values without any conversion since none is needed, the coloured square image is fine now, but a strange issue is that the fox image has now lost all colour. I can see why padding & stride is needed, the image is distorted because of it: distorted, colourless image

Try a monochrome bitmap and/or make it a multiple of 8 or better 16 in each direction. Also make it small and with very distinctive vertical bands and then it should be possible to deduce what is throwing it out. Initial guess would be padding at end of row glitch.

Could you add a screenshot please?

There are a huge number of ways to encode a single image to BMP.  You need to look at all the header fields to do it correctly.  Judging by the sample the RGB components are side by side instead of interleaved.

@catnip I am not sure what you mean by PDF sample, the PDF I am testing has the image properly stored in it & will display fine in any PDF reader. Here's the PDF I am using 'test4.pdf': https://filetransfer.io/data-package/pUOQGiKQ#link

Related: GDI is outdated and you are not going far with it. Use Direct2D.

Before you start resizing, inspenct image 1:1. There is requirement for stride (rows have to be aligned on DWORD boundary). With 3 bytes per pixel, you need to add padding unless width is divisible by 4.

It looks to me like your scan lines actually have 4 bytes per pixel and you have declared them to be 3 bytes per pixel. As a result the cat's ears move to the right by 233/4 ~ 58 pixels with each successive scan line. It would be a lot easier to see this with a nice simple test image instead of a murky blue cat in a coal cellar.

To update, I tried the image K J linked to me & the colours are mostly fine, though they have some kind of weird serration, the back & white though is completely messed up, I've updated the post to include the image

Can you update the question to include the image you are expecting to see?

Blue colors are perhaps caused by using RGB instead BGR. You can swap R and B or use BI_BITFIELDS. Read BITMAPINFOHEADER documentation about stride. Post decompressed raw data with width and height you think it has. There are not that many combinations to try. And please don't use resizing for now.

You cannot use bmp_header.biWidth = pt_to_dip(img_obj.width, 96);. You have to have original image width in pixels here.

To use the RGB image directly you may use BI_BITFIELDS with slight performance hit. Other solution is to go through all pixels and swap R and B components. You also need to get correct value for the bmp_header.biWidth and pad each bitmap row to the DWORD boundary (when rows are not DWORD aligned already).

Now change to bmp_header.biWidth=2562; bmp_header.biHeight=-1602;.Because 3*2562 is not divisible by 4, after each 7686 bytes, two padding bytes are needed so each row will occupy 7688 bytes. Stride calculation is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfoheader

the help with byte padding here is appreciated, but isn't exactly what I need. My issue right now is the striping that is occuring in the fox image (BGR byte order) & the coloured square image (RGB byte order) what is that? if it is to do with the byte padding then could someone elaborate a bit further why it causes the striping. Also can someone help me find a way to check the byte order RGB or BGR? thanks.

The default order for GDI is BGR. The correct stride is essential. Wrong biWidth or not padding when required, could cause shearing, stripping, interleaving (some rows could be displayed with correct component order, some with swapped one). Have you tried width and height values from my previous comment?

Or use bmp_header.biWidth = img_obj.width; bmp_header.biHeight = -img_obj.height; I assume that these are expressed in pixels. If not, inspect other properties. Recalculating will lead to rounding, off by 1 errors and consequently to shearing and other problems.

I would like to elaborate on the image size, PDF documents to my knowledge use the Points (PT) measurement to store sizes such as width & height, I'm assuming here that is the case for image objects too, winGDI expects the size in PX & for my device PX = DIP so I used my existing pt_to_dip() function to convert instead of putting in the size stated in the PDF

This was posted many times above. The image width is 2562 pixels, the height is 1602 pixels. Please post img_obj.width and img_obj.height values. Your last screenshot shows that there is some ratio between nedded and used width (wrong width value is used).

Sorry for the ridiculous amount of mistakes but so far I have been lead to believe that all units in a PDF were simply in standard Pt or Pdf units, & it does work for displaying text & other elements, but I couldn't find anywhere that stated otherwise for image objects, or really gave any in-depth detail of them. K J, I see what you are trying to say, removing the pt_to_dip conversion corrects the striping issue & now it seems the only remaining issue is resizing to hwnd & colours. the all pdf units are 1/72 of an inch is not the case here, the image Height & with values are what is in the obj

Still, now I can see to some extent what padding & stride seem to be for, I assume that is why the image has become a bit vertically distorted, there's a diagonal stripe with a right-to-left gradient for the image, which means that the image rows are indeed not aligned. also, despite me having corrected this issue, that coloured square image K J gave me is fine, but for whatever reason now the fox image displays no colour anymore, maybe because of the padding I'm not sure exactly, thanks for all of your help though, GDI isn't that well documented (for raw streams) so you've all helped a lot.

Previously you multiplied width by 96/72 = 4/3 which made it divisible by 4 - no padding needed. 2562 is not divisible by 4. You need padding or decode image into 32 bits. 32 bit image is always alligned so it doesn't require any padding.

The image distortion was indeed caused by not accounting for image stride, now that I 1. account for image stride
2. have the width & height set to the proper values
3. have the image data properly converted from BGR to RGB if needed
4. properly use the winGDI functions
Both image will render fine, here's the complete code:
LRESULT CALLBACK main_wnd_proc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param) {
    HDC hdc;
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        OutputDebugStringA("\nPAINTING...");
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        for (const image_object& img_obj : img_objs) {
            // init image info
            BITMAPINFOHEADER bmp_header = {};
            bmp_header.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmp_header.biWidth = img_obj.width;
            bmp_header.biHeight = -img_obj.height; // Negative height for top-down DIB
            bmp_header.biPlanes = 1; // must be set to 1
            bmp_header.biBitCount = img_obj.bits_per_component * 3; // BPP = BPC * num components
            bmp_header.biCompression = BI_RGB; // RGB-type data, no compression

            /* calculates image stride, which must be a multiple of 4 bytes for Windows DIBs
            bits per row = bmp_header.biWidth * bmp_header.biBitCount
            when this value is divided by 32 to convert bit count, we need to round up to the next multiple of 32 bits so + 31 to BPR
            multiply 32-bit unit count by 4 to get unit count back in bytes for final stride value */
            int stride = ((bmp_header.biWidth * bmp_header.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4;
            bmp_header.biSizeImage = stride * abs(bmp_header.biHeight);

            BITMAPINFO bmi = {};
            bmi.bmiHeader = bmp_header;

            // copy raw image bits to buffer for rendering
            void* raw_bits = malloc(bmp_header.biSizeImage);
            if (raw_bits != nullptr) {
                // Copy the image data row by row, accounting for stride
                const unsigned char* src = img_obj.image_stream.data(); // source stream
                unsigned char* dst = static_cast<unsigned char*>(raw_bits); // destination stream
                int row_size = img_obj.width * (img_obj.bits_per_component * 3 / 8); // Bytes per row without padding
                for (int y = 0; y < img_obj.height; ++y) {
                    memcpy(dst, src, row_size);
                    // this converts BGR byte order image data into RGB byte order for rendering
                    // (I still need a way to tell which byte order an image is, BGR or RGB) 
                    for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i += 3) { 
                        std::swap(dst[i], dst[i + 2]); // Swap R & B type bytes
                    }
                    src += row_size; // Move to next row in source data
                    dst += stride;  // Move to next row in destination, including padding
                }
            }

            SetStretchBltMode(hdc, HALFTONE); // to even out image colours
            // DI Bits will be set to the current device context & stretched to fit the window area
            StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, 1500, 900,
                0, 0, bmp_header.biWidth, abs(bmp_header.biHeight),
                raw_bits, &bmi,
                BI_RGB, SRCCOPY);

            // free buffer memory & render image by releasing device context
            free(raw_bits);
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            break;
        }

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, w_param, l_param);
    }
    return 0;
} 

Thanks for all of your help, here's the image, now rendered correctly: the final code, working perfectly
